# Firebase cached document added to reads billing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had impression that cashed documents wont be added to total read doc's but doing refresh on my page that gets 50 documents, my document read just keeps increasing.

[image]

```
const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
const userQuery = query(usersRef, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));

export const getUsers = async () => {
  const docs = (await getDocs(userQuery)).docs;
  const res = docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })) as Users[];
  return res;
};
```

And after 5 refresh to just get data again its now
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior.  There is no use cache on queries while your application is online and able to query Firestore directly.  The [persistence layer provided by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is primarily for offline queries.

If you want your query to only consider the persistence layer in a query, then you need to specify that in your query using a [source option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options).  Be aware that this data might be out of date and return inaccurate results.  Also be aware that the SDK may prune data from the cache at will, leading to unpredictable results.

You might want to read: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329